# Installing dependencies as a non root user

Tags: software-installation, non-root-user, dependencies

Can anyone please tell what are the steps to installing libxml2 on a server without root privileges? In a manner so it can be seen by other packages? I have installed it but do not know what is the correct location for it and what variable should be set to make it visible. Please help! I have to install a large number of dependencies and I am stuck at the first step!

Comment: If you can stomach installing all dependencies from source, this answer can help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73657/34796

Comment: probably you can try this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5535/non-root-package-managers

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy way to do this, if any...
You can try going with following way, I've done it once and I said: "Never more".

1. Basically you need to download source of package with wget or with apt-get or whatever...
2. Go to the downloaded package directory with `cd my_package`
3. Issue: `./configure --prefix=$HOME` or if you don't want the directory to be in root of your HOME them create new sub-directory in your HOME and alter command accordingly.
4. make
5. make install

This should be the steps.

Good luck with it :)

Comment: You might need more dependencies (newer version of libXYZ than is installed, maybe a compiler...), there is a reason package managers exist.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. But don't I also need to set path variables for the dependencies? I also don't know how to do that :(  I have put the libxml2 file in the structure/home/username/usr/lib to avoid putting it directly into the root. The other dependencies that need to be able to see these are also in the same folder.

Comment: By the way i tried this... and it gives "Cannot create regular file : Permission denied" error message when running - make install